# camera settings to imitate my camera

Tags: camera

Well, I want to imitate the same camera settings in blender as in photograph that I have taken, in order to edit rendered stills into the same picture I have captured. However I'm having trouble setting up the camera in blender to simulate my camera.

Maybe someone can tell me how to set up the camera?

The picture was taken with a large format camera on a 4x5 film format ( that is 4 inches by 5 inches) with a 121mm lens.

How would I set up a blender camera to simulate this perspective?

---

farge format film cameras are not included in the camera presets, how can I set them up in blender?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can match a camera in blender.

1. Select your camera
2. Go into the camera properties.
   [image]
3. Set the Focal length of your camera to 121.
   [image]
4. Set the Sensor Fit to Horizontal
   [image]
5. Set the width value to 127 (which is 5 inches in millimeters).

You will need to make your image resolution fit a 4:5 aspect ratio.

1. Enter the camera properties
2. Set the width and height accordingly.

To make a new **Preset** click on the plus sign next to cemera presets
[image]

Add a name to it (Click on save focal length if you want to include the lens in the preset).

[image]

Once created the preset will be available for future projects.

[image]